Automatic cleanup of unused unix sockets
Background: I am forwarding a local unix socket to a remote unix socket over SSH (-R /tmp/remote:/tmp/local) so a remote client can connect to it. And (given a recent enough ssh version) it works.
The snag is that /tmp/remote survives the termination of the ssh connection that created it, meaning that subsequent attempts to forward the local socket will fail until /tmp/remote is somehow removed. Ssh (now) has StreamLocalBindUnlink, which sounds promising, but actually works in reverse (with -L, unlinking local socket). There is no StreamRemoteBindUnlink.
So I am left with the (ugly, insecure) solution of using a unix-to-tcp forward and a wrapper script for the client that socats a unix socket to the TCP socket - socat cleans up after itself automatically. I looked into leveraging .bash_logout, but it's error prone and even uglier.
Any way to automatically clean up unused unix sockets?
Edit:
While I have not tried it yet, it appears that cleanup of the REMOTE endpoint may be done by setting  StreamLocalBindUnlink yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config of the remote machine.

You could make this into a script which first deletes the remote file like so:
ssh user@host rm /tmp/remote

and then you run your forwarding with ssh -R remote:local user@host.
Another way I can think of is using a random name instead of fixed /tmp/remote. Using mktemp -u you can get a random name to use on the remote. Of course you will need a cron job to clean those or relay on /tmp being cleaned on reboot and you have to pass that name to whatever app needs the socked on the other side.
